# How to link login page and registration page in JAVA? (and also how to connect to MySQL database?)

Tags: java, mysql, database, user-interface, authentication

I'm new to JAVA, and struggling to build a login system. I'm trying to build a login and registration form which can connect to MySQL local database with JAVA. The main problem is that I wrote two separate JAVA files which are "LoginPage.java" and "RegistrationPage.java", but I don't know to link them together. I mean if I click "create a new account" in login page, I want to go to registration page. How can I do that? And the second problem is, if I try to register a new account, it should save the user info in Mysql local database, but it's not working. Can anyone help me? Please give me any feedback, I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

This is LoginPage.java :

```
package login_register_form;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class LoginPage implements ActionListener{
// frame
JFrame frame;
// inputs
JTextField username = new JTextField();;
JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();;
// labels
JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username");
JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
JLabel createAccountLabel = new JLabel("Create a New Account");
// button
JButton loginButton = new JButton("Log In");

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                LoginPage window = new LoginPage();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public LoginPage() {
    createWindow();
    initialize();
    actionEvent();
}

/**
 * Create a main window
 */
public void createWindow() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Login Page");
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1113, 806);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    
    
    
    // label: orange colored background
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(new Color(255,165,0,200));
    panel.setBounds(300, 150, 500, 472);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    
    // Label: scaled background
    JLabel background = new JLabel("");
    background.setBounds(6, 6, 1100, 772);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/background.jpg"));
    Image img = icon.getImage();
    Image imgScale = img.getScaledInstance(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon scaledIcon = new ImageIcon(imgScale);
    background.setIcon(scaledIcon);
    frame.getContentPane().add(background);
    
    // title: "Login Page"
    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Login Page");
    lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.BOLD, 19));
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(196, 40, 107, 29);
    panel.add(lblNewLabel_1);
    
    // input: user name
    username.setBounds(145, 156, 210, 39);
    panel.add(username);
    username.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: password
    password.setBounds(145, 207, 210, 39);
    panel.add(password);
    
    // Label: user name
    usernameLabel.setBounds(49, 167, 79, 16);
    panel.add(usernameLabel);
    
    // Label: password
    passwordLabel.setBounds(49, 218, 79, 16);
    panel.add(passwordLabel);
    
    // Label: create a new account
    createAccountLabel.setBounds(182, 407, 138, 16);
    panel.add(createAccountLabel);
    createAccountLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            
        }
    });
    
    // Button: Log in
    loginButton.setBounds(190, 304, 120, 52);
    panel.add(loginButton);
    

    
}
public void actionEvent() {
    // Adding action listener to buttons
    loginButton.addActionListener(this);    
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == loginButton) {
        try {
        // Creating Connection Object
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase", "root", "root");
        PreparedStatement Pstatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT USERNAME`, `PASSWORD` FROM `user` WHERE `USERNAME` = ? AND `PASSWORD` = ?");
        Pstatement.setString(1, username.getText());
        Pstatement.setString(2, String.valueOf(password.getPassword()));
        ResultSet result = Pstatement.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successfully");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username OR Password");
            username.setText("");
            password.setText("");
        }
        
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    
    }
}
}
```

And this is my RegisterPage.java :

```
package login_register_form;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;


import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;


public class RegisterPage implements ActionListener{



// frame
JFrame frame;
// Options of position input
String[] position = {"Admin", "Manager", "Assistant"};
// inputs
JTextField firstName = new JTextField();
JTextField lastName = new JTextField();
JTextField userName = new JTextField();
JTextField email = new JTextField();
JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
JPasswordField confirmPW = new JPasswordField();
JComboBox positionComboBox = new JComboBox(position);
// labels
JLabel firstnameLabel = new JLabel("First Name");
JLabel lastnameLabel = new JLabel("Last Name");
JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("User Name");
JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
JLabel confirmPWLabel = new JLabel("Re-Password");
JLabel emailLabel = new JLabel("Email");
JLabel positionLabel = new JLabel("Position");
// buttons
JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");
JButton cancelButton  = new JButton("Cancel");


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                RegisterPage window = new RegisterPage();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application. Calling methods from constructor
 */
public RegisterPage() {
    createWindow();     
    initialize();
    actionEvent();
    
}

/**
 * Create a main window
 */
public void createWindow() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Registration Page");
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1113, 806);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    
    
    // panel: orange colored background
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(new Color(255,165,0,200));
    panel.setBounds(300, 150, 500, 472);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    
    // label: scaled background 
    JLabel background = new JLabel("");
    background.setBounds(6, 6, 1100, 772);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/background.jpg"));
    Image img = icon.getImage();
    Image imgScale = img.getScaledInstance(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon scaledIcon = new ImageIcon(imgScale);
    background.setIcon(scaledIcon);
    frame.getContentPane().add(background);
    
    // title: "Register Page"
    JLabel registerPage = new JLabel("Register Page");
    registerPage.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.BOLD, 19));
    registerPage.setBounds(182, 40, 135, 29);
    panel.add(registerPage);
    
    // input: first name        
    firstName.setBounds(145, 76, 210, 32);
    panel.add(firstName);
    firstName.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: last name
    lastName.setBounds(145, 120, 210, 32);
    panel.add(lastName);
    lastName.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: user name
    userName.setBounds(145, 164, 210, 32);
    panel.add(userName);
    userName.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: password
    password.setBounds(145, 208, 210, 32);
    panel.add(password);
    
    // input: confirm password
    confirmPW.setBounds(145, 252, 210, 32);
    panel.add(confirmPW);
    
    // input: emailLabel
    email.setBounds(145, 296, 210, 32);
    panel.add(email);
    email.setColumns(10);
    
    // input: position
    positionComboBox.setBounds(145, 340, 210, 32);
    panel.add(positionComboBox);
    
    // label: first name
    firstnameLabel.setBounds(36, 84, 85, 16);
    panel.add(firstnameLabel);
    
    // label: last name
    lastnameLabel.setBounds(36, 128, 85, 16);
    panel.add(lastnameLabel);
    
    // label: user name
    usernameLabel.setBounds(36, 172, 85, 16);
    panel.add(usernameLabel);
    
    // label: password
    passwordLabel.setBounds(36, 216, 85, 16);
    panel.add(passwordLabel);
    
    // label: re-password
    confirmPWLabel.setBounds(36, 260, 85, 16);
    panel.add(confirmPWLabel);
    
    // label: emailLabel
    emailLabel.setBounds(36, 304, 85, 16);
    panel.add(emailLabel);
    
    // label: position
    positionLabel.setBounds(36, 347, 101, 16);
    panel.add(positionLabel);
    
    // button: cancel
    cancelButton.setBounds(109, 400, 117, 40);
    panel.add(cancelButton);
            
    // button: register
    registerButton.setBounds(275, 400, 117, 40);
    panel.add(registerButton);
            
}
public void actionEvent() {
    // Adding action listener to buttons
    registerButton.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());
    cancelButton.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == registerButton) {
        try {
            //Creating Connection Object
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase","root", "root");
            //Prepared Statement
            PreparedStatement Pstatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into user values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            // Specifying the values of it's parameter
            Pstatement.setString(1, firstName.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(2, lastName.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(3, userName.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(4, password.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(5, confirmPW.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(6, email.getText());
            Pstatement.setString(7, positionComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
            //Checking for the password match
            if (password.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(confirmPW.getText())) {
                // Executing query
                Pstatement.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Registered Successfully");
            } 
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password did not match");
                // Clearing confirm password fields
                confirmPW.setText("");
            }
        
        
        
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource()==cancelButton) {
        // Clearing Fields
        firstName.setText("");
        lastName.setText("");
        userName.setText("");
        password.setText("");
        confirmPW.setText("");
        email.setText("");
        positionComboBox.setSelectedItem("Admin");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the login page, if you want to go to the register page, you should add a button Register in the login window.
Then you should add the following code in its event handler.

```
RegisterPage rp = new RegisterPage(LoginPage.this);
setVisible(false);
rp.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Okay, I will try that! Thank you!

Comment: I just added 
frame.setVisible(false);
new RegisterPage();
in the mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) method, and it works!
Thank you!

Comment: @TSK, you can vote the answer up since it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

On the create new account on the login page add ==> new RegisterPage(); after the mouse clicked.

For the database, it depends really on the error you are getting and how your database table/attributes are constructed.

Comment: create database myDatabase;
use myDatabase;
create table user( 
FIRSTNAME varchar(20), 
LASTNAME varchar(20), 
USERNAME varchar(20) not null, 
PASSWRD varchar(20), 
CONFIRMPASSWORD varchar(20),
EMAIL varchar(20),
POSITION varchar(20) ); 
This is how I wrote for the mySQL..

Comment: btw, Thank you for the answering